# C# VSTO word AddIn Throws value does not fall within expected error

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, word-addins

I am new to VSTO word Addin,the end goal is to check if the custom document property exists.Read all the available articles online with no breakthrough.

Started of with this code

```
public void chk()
{
   if (this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties["ObjectType"].Value = 0)
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please select an object");
   }
}
```

This throws the error

[Value does not fall within bounds error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvnIr.png)

Modified the code to create a custom document property object as below and it gives me the same error on

> if(this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties["ObjectType"].Value
> = 0)

```
public void chk()
{
      dynamic properties = null;
      properties = this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties;
      properties.Add("Name",false,Office.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString, "ObjectType");
      properties.Add("LinkToContent",false, Office.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeBoolean,false);
      properties.Add("Type",false,Office.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeNumber, 0);
                   
      if(this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties["ObjectType"].Value = 0)
      {
          MessageBox.Show("Please select an object");
       }
}
```

Requesting you to suggest the steps to fix the issue. Please let me know if more information is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over all properties and check their names, compare two approaches:

```
void TestProperties()
{
    Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentProperties properties;
    properties = (Office.DocumentProperties)this.CustomDocumentProperties;

    if (ReadDocumentProperty("Project Name") != null)
    {
        properties["Project Name"].Delete();
    }

    properties.Add("Project Name", false,
        Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoDocProperties.msoPropertyTypeString,
        "White Papers");
}

private string ReadDocumentProperty(string propertyName)
{
    Office.DocumentProperties properties;
    properties = (Office.DocumentProperties)this.CustomDocumentProperties;

    foreach (Office.DocumentProperty prop in properties)
    {
        if (prop.Name == propertyName)
        {
            return prop.Value.ToString();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer Eugene , after the condition returns false , I still get the same error on this.Application.ActiveDocument.CustomDocumentProperties["ObjectType"].Value = 0. Does this do the same thing of checking if the property exists?